# Conditionally print css style in Wordpress

Tags: css, conditional-tags

I posted this on Stackoverflow and as suggested I am reposting it here if thats ok. Didnt knew there was a Wordpress section of the site :)

I am working on a Wordpress theme and want to give the option to choose between a boxed layout and a full width layout.

For this purpose I created a variable in my header.php:

```
<head>
    <?php
        $isBoxedLayout = true;
    ?>
...
</head>
```

Down in the body I am asking if the variable is set:

```
<?php if($isBoxedLayout) { echo '<div id="boxed">'; } ?>
...
<?php if($isBoxedLayout) { echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

This works fine so far. But now I also want to change some css styles if this variable is set. My problem is that I am not so good in PHP yet so my solution would be something like this:

```
<head>
    <?php
        $isBoxedLayout = true;
    ?>
    ...
    if ($isBoxedLayout) {
        echo '<style type="text/css">';
        echo '#container {width:999px;}';
        echo '</style>';
    }
</head>
```

But I think this is not good programming because my header.php file would soon be full of code and confusing if I would add some other options. So logically I should create a variable or an array maybe in the functions.php file and outsource my code like this:

```
$isBoxedLayout = true;

if ($isBoxedLayout) {
    function boxed_css_styles() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">';
        echo '#container {width:999px;}';
        echo '</style>';
    }
}
```

Is my thinking right? And if so how would I access the functions I create in my index.php or header.php or whatever. Or would it work to print the styles in the functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `body_class()` in your templates:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This creates extra classes on the `body` element. Then filter its values in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( Array $classes ) {

    if ( $GLOBALS[ 'isBoxedLayout' ] )
        $classes[] = 'isBoxedLayout';

    return $classes;
});
```

Now you can move all CSS declarations for that to your stylesheet:

```css
.isBoxedLayout #container {
    width:999px;
}
```